# jquery .ready and height of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Might seem like a trivial question but I've run into an issue while using jQuery. When I try and get the height for an element within a .ready I am always given zero.

```
$(function() {
  $('#my-elem').height() // Always gives me zero.
});
```

If I put code in a delay with setTimeout() around the height check (say of .5s) then the height is correctly reported back to me. I'm guessing that this is because the styles haven't had a chance to be applied yet?

The only solution I've found to this problem is to use an interval to poll the height of the element until it becomes non-zero but this seems overkill to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: #my-elem is div,span,img or what

Comment: Is the element hidden and then shown? Try with `$(window).load()` event which fires a bit later than docready.

Comment: Try to put the script at the bottom of the page

Comment: No this won't help; in fact, this means that the script fires before DOMReady (document.ready) event.

Comment: Show us the HTML and also a fiddle, if possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `document.ready` event signals that the HTML DOM is ready for accessing via Javascript, but **that doesn't mean that the elements have already rendered**.

In fact, that's the whole shebang behind `ready`: it's a means for you to start manipulating your document's HTML DOM *without having to wait for the page to finish loading*. It's safe to assume that at `document.ready`, your elements are not yet displayed on the page.

Now, that comes with a caveat: if the elements haven't rendered yet, how can the browser / Javascript know what its resolving height is? `.height()` may give zero at `document.ready` because of this. It's probably best to wait until `load` instead of `ready` when it comes to pulling box dimensions from the layout.

Comment: I think _most of the time (if not every time)_ should be read as _on rare occasions_

Comment: I was speaking from experience, but let me rephrase that to be more generic.