# clientWidth and clientHeight returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why clientWidth/Height return 0 on IE, Chrome and Safari? but on Firefox and Opera works fine.
I used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var imgLength = imgs.length;

    for (var i = 0; i <= imgLength - 1; i++) {

        var imgWidth = imgs[i].clientWidth;
        var imgHeight = imgs[i].clientHeight;

        $('img').eq(i).attr({
            width: imgWidth,
            height: imgHeight
        });

        console.log(imgWidth);
    }

    console.log(imgLength);

});
```

any idea? Thanks.

I tried with window.load with clientwidth its works fine for Firefox, Chrome and Opera but he others not

Comment: I've recently answered on a similar question; you may want [to read that as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11116604/304588). Seems like the same problem.

Comment: If you are using jquery pls use innerWidth() property rather then client width

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal ~ in this particular example, no, it's not better to use jQuery. It's generally faster to reference native properties than to call jQuery functions, and the OP has a handle on a native JS DOM object anyway; why go through the trouble of wrapping that in a jQuery object, and incurring additional overhead?

Answer (score -1):

Try change doctype.
http://forums.asp.net/post/1515655.aspx 
I'm not sure, but I solved this problem so.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to get dimensions including margins and borders try using JQuery functions `outerWidth` and `outerHeight`. They should take care about crossbrowser differences. http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

If you want to get only dimensions of an element contents (without margins, borders, paddings) use `width` and `height`. http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score -6):

I think it would be better if you use JQuery to get the height and width, as it works fine in all browsers, so your code would be something like this :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {


     var imgs = $('img');
     var imgLength = imgs.length;

     for(var i=0; i<= imgLength-1;i++){

         var imgWidth = imgs[i].width();
         var imgHeight = imgs[i].height();

         $('img').eq(i).attr({width:imgWidth, height: imgHeight});

         console.log(imgWidth);
     }

     console.log(imgLength); 

});
```