# ClientWidth is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing hide/show of a column in a table using jQuery. Sometimes i am getting clientWidth value as 0(that time parent element of table i.e a div width is reduced compared to that table, so some part of the table is not shown) and sometimes value. While clientWidth is 0 creating problem for me. Why clientWidth is 0.. after the page is fully loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging js..we are not getting exact clientwidth, because of css class attached to it. Even empty css class or undefined css class also affecting Width and height of the element. We changed to in line style to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is running in `document.ready` function and not in `document.load`, you can take a look to a similar question: [clientWidth and clientHeight returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133069/clientwidth-and-clientheight-returns-0)

In document.ready your elements are ready to be manipulated in the DOM, but they can not be yet displayed on the page.
Starting from this you can try to execute your script in `document.load` function; in this function clientWidth of your elements have to be a value.

Comment: User can only trigger the event of hide/show after fully loading of document. After the HTML page load when clicking Hide anchor in a table, i am hiding the column/row. But clientWidth is 0 for me