# Cross-Browser Image Preview Effect

Tags: javascript, webkit

I have attempted to create an [image preview effect](http://codepen.io/Joshuasm32/full/vaksz) using JavaScript that opens any image clicked in full screen mode.  The image itself uses the following code to center itself based upon its size.

**CSS** | [**See All**](http://codepen.io/Joshuasm32/pen/vaksz?editors=010) | [**Result**](http://codepen.io/Joshuasm32/full/vaksz)

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

**Simplified Javascript** | [**See All**](http://codepen.io/Joshuasm32/pen/vaksz?editors=001) | [**Result**](http://codepen.io/Joshuasm32/full/vaksz)

```
el.style.margin = "-" + el.height / 2 + "px -" + el.width / 2 + "px";
```

This code [functions properly](http://oi62.tinypic.com/xer4o8.jpg) in Firefox, but in Webkit browsers the image is pushed into the top-left corner and has obscure negative margins.  Why does this Javascript not work in Webkit browsers?  How should I go about fixing this code?

Comment: Obscure? You have a minus sign right there in your code.

Comment: @isherwook Please see this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-element-with-positionfixed  A positive margin should be produced.  The code works in CSS, but when using Javascript a problem occurs in Webkit.

Comment: Ah. Looks like Chrome is using the actual image dimensions, while FF is using your applied CSS dimensions.

Comment: Please show more of your JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
popupImage.style.margin = "-" + popupImage.clientHeight / 2 
    + "px -" + popupImage.clientWidth / 2 + "px";
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/623174/1264804

Comment: Might be best to open a new question.

Comment: There seems to be a problem in Safari that does not occur in Chrome or Opera...  http://oi57.tinypic.com/2meptsj.jpg

Comment: Looks like Safari isn't applying the margins at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133069/clientwidth-and-clientheight-returns-0