# How to get div height using javascript

Tags: asp.net, performance, html

I'm having an div in my web form and 1 grid-view inside that div.

```
<div id="divGrid" style="max-height:615px;width:100%;overflow-X:auto;overflow-Y:auto;" >
                                       <asp:GridView ID="gridEdit" GridLines="Vertical" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                                            ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                                            Font-Names = "Arial"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" style="color:Black;"
                                            Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#CCDDFB" >
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No.">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex + 1%>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Bold="false" />
                                            <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle"/>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </div>
```

Now i need to check height of div tag using java script.When i use

> alert(document.getElementById("divGrid").style.height);

It always shows blank alert box.Can any one tell me how can i check div height using java script.

Comment: Might you have jQuery installed?

Answer (score 2):

**Update - re first comment:**

The 2 most likely cases you're dealing with:

1. there are other styles that cause the element to never report a height. Check with chrome's developer tools the height reported for the element after the page has loaded
2. you're checking too early in the script, and the page hasn't fully loaded yet. Try calling the same .height on a link on click to check if it behaves the same.

---

try: `alert(document.getElementById("divGrid").clientHeight);`

Comment: alert(document.getElementById("divGrid").clientHeight);
Shows 0 in alert box.But my problem is solved by using 
alert(document.getElementById('divGrid').scrollHeight);

Comment: hmm, that's odd. Double check you get the right result in all browsers, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11116604/66372 for what I meant with #2. #1 usually happens when you have absolute positioning in the inner elements, and I think also when floating them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var a;
        a = $("#divGrid").height();
        alert(a);
        a = $("#divGrid").innerHeight();
        alert(a);
        a = $("#divGrid").outerHeight();
        alert(a);
    });
```

you can simply try this. :)