# Clientheight does not work in Chrome, what can i do?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to fix this in Chrome because the `clientHeight` property does not work in Chrome?

```
function getMiddle (param1,param2) {
    var circle = document.getElementById(param1);
    var div = document.getElementById(param2);
    var clientHeight = div.clientHeight;
    var new_height = Math.round(clientHeight/2)-25;
    circle.style.marginTop =new_height + "px";
    circle.style.visibility="visible";
 }
```

Comment: So what happens with div.clientHeight? Throws an error, or returns "undefined"?

Comment: in Firefox, clientheight is 176, but in Chrome ,it is 0 @@

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery .ready and height of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115179/jquery-ready-and-height-of-element)