# Jquery natural width of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to send a multiplier to my server so I can properly manage my image. The client can upload images, and onload I want to immediatly figure out the difference between natural and client width. The image is in a container which is 350px and the image is set to `min-width: 100%;` I tried below, and oddly it worked a few times.

When I run this I get a correct naturalWidth, but clientWidth is 0.

Below is a method from jcrop. And some added functionality to get the natural and client width.

```
$('#target').Jcrop({
            onChange : updatePreview,
            onSelect : updatePreview,
            aspectRatio : xsize / ysize
        }, function() {
            // Use the API to get the real image size
            var bounds = this.getBounds();
            boundx = bounds[0];
            boundy = bounds[1];
            // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
            jcrop_api = this;

            // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
            $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
        });

        function updatePreview(c) {

            $('#xmargin').val(Math.round(c.x));
            $('#ymargin').val(Math.round(c.y));
            $('#x2').val(Math.round(c.w));
            $('#y2').val(Math.round(c.h));

            var clientW = document.getElementById("target").clientWidth;
            var naturalW = document.getElementById("target").naturalWidth; 

            var multiply = naturalW/clientW;

            $('#multiply1').val(clientW); //Returns 0
            $('#multiply2').val(naturalW); //Returns correct value

            if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                var rx = xsize / c.w;
                var ry = ysize / c.h;

                $pimg.css({
                    width : Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                    height : Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                    marginLeft : '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                    marginTop : '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: See related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133069/clientwidth-and-clientheight-returns-0
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115179/jquery-ready-and-height-of-element/11116604#11116604
It seems that the javascript is triggering before the image is rendered; hence it's width is still 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but neither gave any information I could use. The thing is I run this method several times, so the img should be ready.

Comment: So have you tried calling it inside a `$(window).load(function() {})`call?